# About the position of “though”

Tags: word-position

> This exercise in my book is before the *Composition series* and I’m just about to go through that section, ***though***, your answer still seems very nice to me.

What did I mean by “though”?

> Which did my words mean,
>
> 1) “***Although***” this exercise in my book is before the *Composition series* and I’m just about to go through that section, your answer still seems very nice to me”
>
> or
>
> 2) “***Although***” your answer still seems very nice to me, this exercise in my book is before the *Composition series* and I’m just about to go through that section”?

Actually, what I wanted to express was the former one. Was I right in my way?

Comment: Sorry to point out that is a wholly contrived example with no useful meaning in the real world.

Specifically there, “though,“ with that comma spoilt everything.

More usefully, the parts about the exercise in your book and the other guy’s answer have nothing to do with each other and can be compared only to the extent that “exercise” and “answers” are interchangeable… Are they?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks for your instructions on this question!